# How to read larger csv file in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, csv

I am new to this. I am trying to load a CSV file whose size is apprx 2.5 GB.

I have an input type file which allows to select file. And onchange of that I am calling a function which contains following :

```
     `var r = new FileReader();
      r.onload = function (e) {
          var contents = e.target.result;
          scope.$apply(function () {
              scope.fileReader = contents;
          });
      };`
```

I am able to read other CSV files except this one.

When I select this CSV file, debugger goes into this function and when it reaches to `r.onload` it breaks and this message is displayed

"Dev tools disconnected from the page."

I want to load it. How it be possible?

Comment: what ? well this is really a big size. never seen something like this

Comment: Yes.. In normal excel csv I am not even able to open it.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome could crash, because FileReader API read contents into memory.
To read a large csv file, you need to use a parser, like [Papa Parse](http://papaparse.com/)